# Visual studio Android SDK Manager not showing the latest Android versions

Tags: android, visual-studio-2017, android-sdk-manager

I recently had a problem with the android sdk manager, precisely by not showing the latest Android versions which I wanted to update to.
In case it provides help, the solution that worked for me is listed below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a pending visual studio update, so, what I did is the following:

**Tools > Extensions and updates > Updates.**

If there is any available VS update, perform it. It might ask for a computer restart.
After that, the missing packages were correctly shown

Comment: to get 8.1/P tools you need VS2017 15.6.x, so this was the pending update